# Is Jmeter Beanshell support invoke function from Kotlin jar file

Tags: java, kotlin, jmeter

I have Kotlin class:

```
class Ping {
    fun ping(from: String): String{
        return "Hello $from"
    }
}
```

I've built jar file from this class. and included it to Jmeter and invoked it in **BeanShell Sampler**:

```
Ping ping = new Ping();

ping.ping("Jmeter");
```

it appear error **Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``Ping ping = new Ping();  ping.ping("Jmeter");'' : Method Invocation ping.ping**

but I tried to change parameter of the method from **string** to **int** it work fine.

Any solution for this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Why you expect beanshell to execute kotlin?

Comment: Use JSR223 Sampler after adding kotlin JSR223 jars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue using:

1. [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html)
2. [Kotlin 1.5](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew15.html) (I copied the following .jars to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) just in case)

   ```
   kotlin-reflect.jar
   kotlin-reflect-sources.jar
   kotlin-stdlib.jar
   kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar
   kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-sources.jar
   kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar
   kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-sources.jar
   kotlin-stdlib-sources.jar
   kotlin-test.jar
   kotlin-test-sources.jar
   ```
3. The following sample code:

   ```
   Ping ping = new Ping();

   log.info(ping.ping("Jmeter"));
   ```

[image]

So double check your .jar file and JMeter Classpath. It also worth trying to put your code inside [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like

```
try {
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    log.info(ping.ping("Jmeter"));
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Beanshell failure", ex);
}
```

this way you will get the root cause of the problem in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so maybe it worth considering migrating to Groovy, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details, it might be the case you won't need any Kotlin code.

Comment: After implementing try catch still can not see the root of the problem error message still the same, however switching to Groovy might be better thank you so much.